# How to create offline map for website using mbtiles database?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, google-maps

I have on e requirement to load map on my website but that should come offline.
m trying to integrate [this](https://github.com/sainsb/tilecannon) but map is not loading.

Error it gives is 404 coz it's not able to find images from mbtiles database.
Also m not able to figure out what is **ESRIPATH** in linked solution.
Path for mbtiles db in Global.asax.cs file:

```
  public static string TILEPATH = "C:/mbtiles/";
    public static string ESRIPATH = @"Qatar_Map\";
    public static string SERVER = "localhost:54450/";
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your given repository, **ESRIPATH** is  *arcgis bundled cache directory path*.

And try **SERVER = 'localhost'** instead of **SERVER = "localhost:54450/"**

Comment: Thanks @AbdurRahim actually m trying to load map tiles from my local server but not able to get it displayed as it fetches it from .mbtiles file which mismatch with my map tiles.